# Sharing object and variable accessing scope in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

am not expert PHP developer but i have been moved from JAVA and suffering from code organization techniques.

I have a controller class which extends MY_Controller calls which have some protected variables like.

```
->User_ID
->Pofile_ID
```

Here the thing , i have a `payamentprocessing` function stored on a separate **php** class file 'PaymentService.php` and i have defined the

`payamentprocessing` function defined their like :

```
 public function processPayment() {
        //load helper and libraries for 
        //validating the input from the form
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //$post = $this->input->post();
        //retrieve form data and sanitize
        $card_number = $this->sanitize($_POST['card_number']);                
}
```

So , what i want is **forexample**

if i instantiate `PaymentService` Class and call `ProcessPayement` Method say in `PaymentController` how can i be able to get `_POST` varibales as global and `$this` context available inside my ProcessPayment method .

Thankyou so much!

Comment: `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));`
        `$this->load->library('form_validation');` working?

Comment: no its not  i want to adopt that style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$post_val=$CI->input->post('YOUR_POST_VARIABLE');
//you can get all post values like this
//$post_vals=$CI->input->post();
```

**Update**:Your final function will be like this

```
 public function processPayment() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI ->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $CI ->load->library('form_validation');       
    $card_number=$this->sanitize($CI->input->post('card_number')); //assuming sanitize is your member function of your current class               
}
```